# Регулярное выражение для получения BBCode URL

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, bbcode

Чем этот код:

```
icons = re.findall(r'<div class="post1" id="_all_groups" style="display: none; position: absolute; z-index: 3;">(.*)</div>', res)  
icons = str(icons[0])
```

концептуально отличается от этого:

```
while i != len(profiles):        
    profiles[i] = str((re.findall(r'[url=(.*)]', profiles[i]))[0])
    print (profiles[i])    
    i = i + 1
```

За исключением того, разумеется, что в первом случае, я обрезаю всего одну строку, а тут несколько строк в списке. Но вот первый код работает идеально, а второй мне выводит только букву `'u'`. А мне нужно получить собственно от `[url=' до ']`, что я не могу сделать...
Содержимое `profiles`:

```
[url=http://forum.sibnet.ru/index.php?showuser=60395]
[url=http://forum.sibnet.ru/index.php?showuser=60395]
[url=http://forum.sibnet.ru/index.php?showuser=60395]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

посмотрим внимательно на регулярное выражение

```
[url=(.*)]
```

квадратные скобки - это не просто символы, а спецзнаки, которые указывают на диапазон значений символов. То есть, к примеру [0-9] - это любая цифра, а [abc] - только один с перечисленных символов. Все спецсимволы, кроме ^ в начале и - теряют свое значение.
Поэтому, это регулярное выражение говорит - `"один символ из u r l = ( . * )"`
Как исправить? элементарно. нужно просто добавить по одному слешу

```
\[url=(.*)\]
```

И все сразу заработает как нужно (проверял).

Comment: огромное спасибо, подзабыл такую деталь, ибо не пользовался раньше этим... я уже извратился и написал по-другому, но ошибку было интересно узнать :)